# CTFramesetterCreateFrame and kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierFirstLineHeadIndent

Tags: ios, core-text, ctframe

I have a receipt of say 200x200px. I want to write inside a text using CTFramesetterCreateFrame and kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierFirstLineHeadIndent. the big problem is that if I want for example to write **this is the text** with kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierFirstLineHeadIndent = 198 then I will have :

```
               t
his is the text
```

the CTFramesetterCreateFrame cut the word **this** ... i want instead to have

```
                .
this is the text
```

how do?

Answer (score 0):

The concise change you need to make to your existing code:

```
CGFloat indent = 198.0; // Adjust this value as needed
// Adjust the rect width to accommodate for the indent
CGRect adjustedRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + indent, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width - indent, rect.size.height);
```

This change ensures that the first line of text is not cut off when using `CTFramesetterCreateFrame` with a specified first-line head indent. Adjust the `indent` value as needed to achieve the desired result.